# How do I know whether my LaTeX file has errors?

Tags: debugging

I have changed the settings in TeXShop so that the console appears only when there are errors. However, I always pops up. 
How can I identify the number of errors I have?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```

The console output is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./MWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2020-02-08>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
No file MWE.aux.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./MWE.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmr12.pfb>
Output written on MWE.pdf (1 page, 8482 bytes).
SyncTeX written on MWE.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on MWE.log.
```

The log output is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.2.10)  4 MAR 2020 13:13
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**MWE.tex
(./MWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2020-02-08>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count167
\c@section=\count168
\c@subsection=\count169
\c@subsubsection=\count170
\c@paragraph=\count171
\c@subparagraph=\count172
\c@figure=\count173
\c@table=\count174
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-02-03 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count175
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
)
No file MWE.aux.
\openout1 = `MWE.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./MWE.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 362 strings out of 481255
 6171 string characters out of 5918611
 236091 words of memory out of 5000000
 15703 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 532636 words of font info for 25 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 24i,4n,21p,136b,97s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmr12.pfb>
Output written on MWE.pdf (1 page, 8482 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 12 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: There are no errors in the log shown (although you should update your system, you have patch level 1 and patch level 5 is current)

Comment: How do I update?

Comment: the same way that you presumably got the patch level 1 release that you have: `tlmgr update --self --all`

Comment: I don't understand. I do not recall actively getting a patch level 1 release. Could you explain further?

Comment: the version you are using was released last month so you must have updated or installed very recently?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Open TeX Live Utility and it will generate a list of all available updates. The use Update All and it will download and install them. By the way TeX Live 2019 is now frozen so the update will be the last one for this distribution.